# Recursive time query

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I am stuck trying to come up with a query to solve my problem, This is what my schema is basically

```
CREATE TABLE Attempts (
  `login` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `success` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'
);
```

and my data looks like this

```
_______________________________________
| login | date                |success|
+-------+---------------------+-------+
| user1 | 2017-12-12 12:00:00 | 0     |
| user1 | 2017-12-12 12:01:00 | 0     |
| user1 | 2017-12-12 12:03:00 | 0     |
| user1 | 2017-12-12 12:05:00 | 1     |
| user2 | 2017-12-12 12:00:00 | 0     |
| user2 | 2017-12-12 12:00:00 | 0     |
| user2 | 2017-12-12 12:00:00 | 0     |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
```

Given this data, I need to figure out if a user has ever had 10 or more unsuccessful attempts in a 15 minute period.  So for `2017-12-12 12:00:00` I would need to `COUNT()` all unsuccessful attempts until `2017-12-12 12:15:00` and for `2017-12-12 12:01:00` I would count all attempts till 2017-12-12 12:16:00

I have tried self joins like

```
SELECT 
  a1.date, GROUP_CONCAT(a2.date)
FROM Attempts as a1
JOIN Attempts as a2
ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, a2.date, a1.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
GROUP BY a1.date;
```

but this doesn't seem correct, I feel like I have solved this issue in the past and the solution is escaping me at the moment.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Luckily, the situation has never arisen

Comment: Hi. "basically", "seem", "feel" & "like" mean nothing. Please read & act on [mcve] and [ask]. Show what parts you have been able to do. (In particular " in a 15 minute period" is not clear. Also your attempt at an example seems probably not what you mean since it is probably trying to talk about the minutes part of times when it is talking about times.  PS Please clarify by editing your post, not by commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.  Using your approach:

```
SELECT a1.date, COUNT(*)
FROM Attempts a1 JOIN
     Attempts a2
     ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, a2.date, a1.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
WHERE a2.success = 0
GROUP BY a1.date
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10;
```

EDIT:

You appear to want this per `login`:

```
SELECT a1.login, a1.date, COUNT(*)
FROM Attempts a1 JOIN
     Attempts a2
     ON a1.login = a2.login and
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, a2.date, a1.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
WHERE a2.success = 0
GROUP BY a1.login, a1.date
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a3e3/8) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this solution and it doesn't seem to work as I would expect.  Given this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a3e3/2.  I would expect the result set to be empty, since there are no instances where 10 or more unsuccessful logins occurred in a 15 minute period.